# Find month have a sum greater than a given number

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ID2mddNPeMRtPVpq16XkAUWBE4j5EK1w8Aiq7CVk6o/edit#gid=1344154694

Column C - N represent month from 1 - 12

I want to find which month have a sum greater than 200.

I use if formula and result is ok but it's too long

Any help to improve the formula

Comment: What is your question? If I understand you correctly, there are two formulas you want to improve, one to calculate the sum of column C-N, and another one to find at which month the sum of all previous months become greater than 200. But you already have formulas for that. Is your question how to improve these formulas so that they're not so long?

Comment: Sorry for confusing question. I have edited that, and Yes my question is how to improve formula so that it's not so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(C2:N*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C:N)^0)))
```

P2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C>=200, 1, 
 IF(MMULT(C2:D*1, ROW(A1:A2) ^0)>=200, 2, 
 IF(MMULT(C2:E*1, ROW(A1:A3) ^0)>=200, 3,
 IF(MMULT(C2:F*1, ROW(A1:A4) ^0)>=200, 4,
 IF(MMULT(C2:G*1, ROW(A1:A5) ^0)>=200, 5,
 IF(MMULT(C2:H*1, ROW(A1:A6) ^0)>=200, 6,
 IF(MMULT(C2:I*1, ROW(A1:A7) ^0)>=200, 7,
 IF(MMULT(C2:J*1, ROW(A1:A8) ^0)>=200, 8,
 IF(MMULT(C2:K*1, ROW(A1:A9) ^0)>=200, 9,
 IF(MMULT(C2:L*1, ROW(A1:A10)^0)>=200, 10,
 IF(MMULT(C2:M*1, ROW(A1:A11)^0)>=200, 11,
 IF(MMULT(C2:N*1, ROW(A1:A12)^0)>=200, 12, )))))))))))))
```

[image]